# DaggerIntentService pug: No injector factory bound for Class<>

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-mvvm

I have IntentService called LoginService I tried to contribute it on loginActivity with LoginScope

Contribute Login Activity to Dagger Graph:

```
    @LoginScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector(
        modules = {
                LoginViewModelModule.class,
                LoginFragmentBuilderModule.class,
                LoginNetworkBuilderModule.class,
                LoginServiceBulderModule.class
        }
)
abstract LoginActivity contributeLoginActivity();
```

Also, I tried to contribute LoginService that extends DaggerIntentService to the Graph :

LoginServiceBulderModule.class:

```
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract LoginService contributeLoginService();
```

LoginService.class :

```
public class LoginService extends DaggerIntentService {
private static final String TAG = "LoginService";

@Inject
LoginFirebaseHelper loginFirebaseHelper;

public LoginService() {
    super("LoginService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent: LoginService");
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION_START_LOGIN)){
        String oracle = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.ORACLE);
        String password = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.PASSWORD);
        loginFirebaseHelper.startLoginFB(oracle, password);
    }
}}
```

I Provided LoginFirebaseHelper:
LoginNetworkBuilderModule.class:

```
    @LoginScope
@Provides
static LoginFirebaseHelper provideLoginFirebaseHelper(Application application, DatabaseReference databaseReference, FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth){
    return new LoginFirebaseHelper(application, databaseReference, firebaseAuth);
}
```

the code works fine when I contribute the Loginservice in the top level of the app on @Singlton (when I provide LoginFirebaseHelper on AppModule and contribute Loginservice to App Component by LoginNetworkBuilderModule.lass) 
But when I use the above code I get next pug

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class<....core.network.service.LoginService>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the module which declares **@ContributesAndroidInjector** for your service into the application.

Only then dagger-support-framework can find out the injector factory for your **LoginService**.

To understand, simply install **LoginServiceBulderModule** into the app component.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {LoginServiceBulderModule.class}) // you need to install it here 
interface AppComponent {

}
```

And I am assuming your application class implements **HasAndroidInjector**. If not follow the guidelines mentioned on https://www.dagger.dev on how to use Dagger Support Android Framework.

Comment: The code works fine when I contribute the Loginservice in the top level of the app on Singlton (when I provide LoginFirebaseHelper on AppModule and contribute Loginservice to AppComponent by LoginNetworkBuilderModule.class and LoginServiceBulderModule.class) But when I contribute Loginservice inside Loginscope in LoginActivity I get the above pug